# testing Meteor React Redux with Jest framework instead of mocha

Tags: reactjs, meteor, redux, jestjs

i develop an application with Meteor, React and Redux using tutorials like https://medium.com/modern-user-interfaces/how-we-redux-part-5-components-bddd737022e1

i have installed some test packages (practicalmeteor:mocha,chai,sinon) or dispatch:mocha (https://atmospherejs.com/dispatch/mocha) to make some full app tests but now, what i would like is to use the jest framework (specially, use the coverage jest feature or snapshots for example).

i don't find how to do this (maybe i have to mock Meteor ...)

is someone doing this ? or have i to continue with mocha.